# How to iterate every item from a list only once

Tags: python, excel, csv, for-loop

So I am comparing 2 csv datasets with each other. Each set's first row is the title row. Each additional row has the values at a given time.
The timestamp has the index 1. My goal is to compare both datasets and transfer the values of the time matching rows to a new excel file.

Dataset 1: cam_data_file.csv

```
Time,Timestamp,blood_pressure_diastolic_value,blood_pressure_systolic_value,heart_rate_value,respiratory_rate_value,sat02_value

07-02-2023 15:01:35.053361,1675778495.053361,69,138,51,80,100

07-02-2023 15:01:36.074203,1675778496.074203,69,138,51,80,100
```

...

Dataset 2: icu_data_file.csv

```
SystemLocalTime,Timestamp,NOM_PRESS_BLD_NONINV_DIA,NOM_PRESS_BLD_NONINV_SYS,NOM_ECG_CARD_BEAT_RATE,NOM_RESP_RATE,NOM_PULS_OXIM_SAT_O2

07-02-2023 15:01:36.027,1675778496.027,69,138,53,20,100

07-02-2023 15:01:37.045,1675778497.045,69,138,53,20,100
```

...

I want to join the matching timestamps from both datasets with a deviation of 0,1. Therefore I open both files in read mode, iterate every row, calculate the difference of both timestamp values and then add the values in their respective column of the new file 'Comparison.xlsx'
This is the code I am using:

```
with open('cam_data_file.csv', 'r') as file1:         
    cam_reader = csv.reader(file1, delimiter=',')     
    kopfzeile1 = next(cam_reader)                     
    cam_daten = list(cam_reader)       
                                                      
with open('icu_data_file.csv', 'r') as file2:        
    icu_reader = csv.reader(file2, delimiter=',')     
    kopfzeile2 = next(icu_reader)                     
    icu_daten = list(icu_reader) 
      
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Comparison.xlsx')          
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Values')                          

index = 1                                     
for a in cam_daten:                                     #Here is the problem I guess
    for b in icu_daten:                                 #Here is the problem I guess
        dif = (float(a[1]) - float(b[1]))     
        if abs(dif) < 0.1:
            worksheet.write(index, 0, index)
            worksheet.write(index, 2, a[0]) 
            worksheet.write(index, 4, a[2])
            ....
```

My problem is that there are more than one value that is in the 0.1 range. So 1 value from cam_data gets matched with 2 values from icu_data. Therefore I have some cam_data values that are double in the Comparison file.
I want every cam_data value added only once to the new file.

I SOLVED IT:

```
for a in cam_daten:                            
    used = False                               
    for b in icu_daten:                        
        dif = (float(a[1]) - float(b[1]))      
        if abs(dif) < 0.1:                     
            used = True                        
            worksheet.write(index, 0, index)
            worksheet.write(index, 2, a[0])           
            worksheet.write(index, 4, a[2])           

#           .....


            index += 1                     
        if used:                           
            break
workbook.close()
```

Comment: just add `break` to quit the loop on the first match?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre where should I add it? and wouldn't it destroy the for loop?

Comment: I think you could use @Jean-FrançoisFabre idea, add the break statement inside the if and in the end.

Comment: add it in the < 0.1 condition

Comment: also: `icu_daten = [zeile for zeile in icu_reader] ` => `icu_daten = list(icu_reader)`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre still does not affect the outcome... any other ideas?

Comment: [edit] your question to show the updated code & problem. A [mcve] would also come handy. We don't have your files and the question isn't about csv anyway. Also show expected values and what you're actually getting.

Comment: Is there anything like a Primary Key in the datasets?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I edited my problem. Is it any clearer now?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver what do you mean by that?

Comment: a bit better. Is it expected that you have empty rows in your csv files?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre no! every row has values. I need the iteration go only once through cam_data. So that for every cam_data values there is a icu_data value. But the values from one timestamp should not repeat.